# Circumstances that might happen in Hall-effect experiment

Tags: forces, magnetic-fields, potential, quantum-hall-effect

In Hall-effect experiment, is it possible that no transverse potential difference will be observed? Under what circumstances might this happen?

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking whether the Hall coefficient can be zero then the answer is that yes it can be. For example in an intrinsic semiconductor there are equal numbers of conduction electrons and holes. Since the Hall effect is opposite for opposite charges the net Hall effect can be zero and no transverse voltage will be observed.